# Magento 2 - How to add customer name in CMS page/block?

Tags: magento2, customer, variables

I need to add the name of the customer into a CMS Site or Block. I tried to insert `{{var customer.name}}` as seen in the [documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/variables-reference.html), but it does not work.

Comment: Can you describe in more details, where you want to added this one?

Comment: In a CMS page or block. The user should see his own name, for example "Hello Mr Vasoya"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create one block file on your custom extension like this :

   ```
   <?php 
   namespace Vendor\Extension\Block

   class Customerinfo  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {
    protected $_session;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session) {
     ...
          $this->_session = $session;
     ...
    } 

    public function getCurrentCustomernameinfo()
    {
       if ($this->_session->isLoggedIn()) {
           return $this->_session->getCustomer()->getName();
       }
    }  
   }
   ```
2. now in create custom phtml file  : `mycustomfile.phtml`

   ```
   <?php echo $block->getCurrentCustomernameinfo(); ?>
   ```
3. Now call this phtml file into you CMS Block or CMS Page.

   ```
   {{block class="Vendor\Extension\Block\Customerinfo" template="mycustomfile.phtml"}}
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Where do I have to store the template file to make it work?

Comment: You need to store the phtml into your extension into path : vendor\extension\view\frontend\templates